# When using componentDidUpdate() how to avoid infinite loop when you're state is an array of objects?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm creating a react-native app and I need one of my components to use a axios get request when I do an action on another component. But the problem is that my component that I need an axios get request from is not being passed any props and the current state and new state is an array of 20+ objects with each at least 10 key value pairs. So I would need a component did update with a good if statement to not go into an infinite loop. I can't do an if statement with prevState to compare with current state because there is only a minor change happening in state. So I need to know how to stop the component Did Update from having an infinite loop.

```
state = {
    favouriteData: []
}

componentDidMount () {
    this.getFavouriteData()
}

componentDidUpdate (prevProps, prevState) {

    if (this.state.favouriteData !== prevState.favouriteData){
        this.getFavouriteData()
    }
}

getFavouriteData = () => {
    axios.get('http://5f46425d.ngrok.io')`enter code here`
    .then(response => {
        const data = response.data.filter(item => item.favourite === true)
        this.setState({
            favouriteData: data
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: Is `getFavouriteData()` always triggered automatically or can be via button click?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are trying to compare 2 object references by doing the following. It will always return since the references are always different.

```
if (this.state.favouriteData !== prevState.favouriteData) {...}
```

To make life easier, we can use Lodash(`_.isEqual`) to deal with deep comparison of objects.

```
state = {
    favouriteData: []
}

componentDidMount () {
    this.getFavouriteData()
}

componentDidUpdate (prevProps, prevState) {
    this.getFavouriteData(prevState.favouriteData)
}

getFavouriteData = (prevData) => {
    axios.get('http://5f46425d.ngrok.io')
    .then(response => {
        const data = response.data.filter(item => item.favourite === true);
        // compare favouriteData and make setState conditional
        if (!prevState || !_.isEqual(prevData, data)) {
            this.setState({
                favouriteData: data
            })
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use react-redux to avoid this kind of issues. Assuming you are not using flux architecture, you can pass this.getFavouriteData() as props to the other component like:

```
<YourComponent triggerFavouriteData = {this.getFavouriteData}/>
```